# Custom table queries in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, csv

I am developing a WordPress site for a client and they would like me to setup a custom page that allows logged in users to query a custom table in the WordPress database. I'll be naming the custom table 'inspectors' and will import the data from a CSV file.

I've found this helpful **[tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/working-custom-database-tables-wordpress/)** on doing this

But the 'fly in the ointment' is that they want the results to be displayed according to location - so the user would enter a postal code or town and will get results for inspectors that are located within a 50 k radius. I'm pretty sure I could manage a basic query to the custom table, but getting it to return location-based results is beyond me.

Is it even possible - and if so, is it worth the time and effort it would take to make it happen - or is there a simple solution I just don't know about?

Also, they also would like me to create a custom form (that is available only to the admin user role) so they can update the info from WordPress and not have to update the info in the spreadsheet. They'd like to be able to export the data in the table to CSV easily too ...

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link and write your own custom queries.

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
```

Comment: Thanks @SyamMohan - it's not the queries I am having the trouble with. It's getting the results to be location based that I don't know how to do.